# TextView: set Html and own SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, html, textview, spannable

I have a string that contain html tags. So for set text into `TextView` I use:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString));
```

It's works good.

Also I have own method `convertText()` with type `SpannableStringBuilder`. In which method I convert text, where I have something like [text="information"]. I use next for set text:

```
textView.setText(convertText(myString), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

For example: `myString = "<h1> This is [text="information"]. </h1>"`
The result must be:
This is INFORMATION. (with h1 formatted text. caps lock of word information works in method convretText() good)

It's also works good. But how I can use these two setText approach in one time?

Comment: please explain with reference or example for better help.

Comment: @Tauqir I have edited my question.